# How to change the material of a ocean as the ripples expand

Tags: materials, ocean-simulation

Sorry if the question does not fit this site. I am new to blender, but I am lost. I want to do a simple animation, where a boat passes in a calm ocean and as its ripples expand, they change the ocean color. I know how to make an ocean, I saw a tutorial on how to make ripples (but not in mesh with a ocean modifier), but I have no idea on how to change the color.

I just need a north, like what should I search for.

Here is a terrible made concept:

[image: time1]

[image: time2]

Comment: OK, I think I know what you’re going for. I think generally the best way to make a ripples from a boat is with dynamic paint, but I’m not sure if you can also use it to make the ocean permanently change color once it’s been affected by the boat. One jerry rig way to do it is to make a second dynamic paint system with an invisible cone that follows the boat around.